# Linux Samba server: files moved into shared directory via 'mv' command are not visible on clients

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba

I've setup a Samba server on Rockey Linux 8. The shared directory can be mounted on Windows / macOS clients and files can be read/write without any issue. The problem is, if I `mv` some file from other path into shared directory, that file will not be visible on SMB clients. I must use `cp` instead.

For example, suppose directory on Linux server is `/home/samba/shared` and I want to share a file originally located at `/home/User1/somedata.txt` (which is is already set to be readable/writable by Samba), and I did this:

```
cp /home/User1/somedata.txt /home/samba/shared/somedata_copied.txt
mv /home/User1/somedata.txt /home/samba/shared/somedata_moved.txt
```

The SMB clients will only see `somedata_copied.txt` (***and*** read/modify it without issue), but not `somedata_moved.txt`; which is **not appeared** in the mounted volume on Windows/macOS clients at all. Calling `systemctl restart smb` does not help.

My current `smb.conf` is minimalist:

```
[global]
    workgroup = MyGroup
    server string = Samba Server %v
    netbios name = MyGroup
    interfaces = lo enp1s0 192.168.2.2/24
    hosts allow = 127. 192.168.3.

    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam

    # printing = cups
    # printcap name = cups
    # cups options = raw
    load printers = no
    wins support = no
    local master = no

[MyShare]
    path = /home/samba/shared
    valid users = @samba
    guest ok = no
    writable = yes
    browsable = yes
```

Did I missed some options in `smb.conf` ?

Comment: any difference in the ownership and/or permissions of those files?

Comment: @JaromandaX I've never heard that `cp` or `mv` will change ownership and/or permission of destination file. And no, their owner, group and permission looks exactly the same in `ls -la`.

Comment: I've never heard that either, I never said it would, just wanted to see what the ownership/permissions actually are

Comment: @JaromandaX the owner/group of both somedata* are `User1.User1`, and permission set to `666`. `User1` is in the group `samba`. And clients are login using `User1` account.

Comment: I believed you when you said they were the same